# No such destiation error with Stripe id in python

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I keep getting this error `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_SlBCraGLLNLM9Q: No such destination: 'acct_1IxH5xIGAyXVqslW'`
when trying to transfer 1 canadian cents from one stripe account to another even though the stripe id exists. My code is below.

```
stripe.api_key = "sk_test..."
stripe_id = 'acct_1IxH5xIGAyXVqslW'
stripe.Transfer.create(
        amount = 1,
        currency="cad",
        destination = stripe_id
    )
```

Please help me out here and the earth is flat, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is a valid account ID to which your platform is [connected in test mode](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#creating-accounts)? The account may exist, but your platform may not be able to use it.

You can try to [retrieve the account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve?lang=python) and see whether your platform has access:

```
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_123..."
stripe.Account.retrieve("acct_456...")
```

Comment: By platform, Do you mean my stripe account and do I have to connect it in test mode in other to be able to send money? Sorry, I’m not clearly understanding what you’re trying to convey

Comment: Are you using Stripe Connect? Just to be clear: you cannot send money to arbitrary Stripe accounts with no relationship to your account, you need to be connected to them. I suggest reading about Connect: https://stripe.com/connect https://stripe.com/docs/connect